# Unable to su into any user

Tags: permissions, su, setuid

After I have fiddled with the folders `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` I restored them, but was not able to `su` into root (and probably other accounts too):

```
Permissions on the password database may be too restrictive
```

This error shows only for unprivileged users.
Furthermore this causes problems with programs that require root privileges too,
therefore rendering me unable to "switch" into administration mode from my normal user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this was caused by the fact that not all permissions had been restored. Specifically the `setuid` bit on `/usr/bin/su` was not set.

After fixing this (as root) with:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/su
```

I was able to `su` as an unprivileged user and use the graphical tools that rely on root permissions.